# How to avoid multiple sequential occurences of a character in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match any alphanumerics that can be separated by one or multiple dots :

1. bertie
2. bert.123
3. bert.01.03.27

but not :

1. .bert (dot is not separating)
2. bert123. (dot is not separating)
3. bert...123 (multiple sequential occurences of dot)

Now i have this `^[^\\.][\w\.]+?[^\\.]$`, but still cannot handle the multiple sequential occurences of the dot character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `^\w++(\.\w++)*$`

At least one alphanumeric character, followed by an arbitrary number of groups of only one dot followed by at least one alphanumeric character.

Comment: It might not be relevant to your short example strings but my solution is slightly more efficient due to putting the optional part at the end instead of the beginning. You can get it by thinking about what the matcher has to do, step by step. And the possessive quantifiers improve it further. But as said, it’s relevant to large strings and lots of them only.

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration ! I tried your solution, and it worked, but i dont understand what is the double plus thing. I understand that a single plus will match one or more occurences.

Comment: It a “possessive quantifier”. Normally the matcher tries to match as much as it can but when the next pattern element doesn’t match it will try to find a match by reducing the number of occurrences. This is called “backtracking”. The second plus sign tells it it shouldn’t do backtracking as we know, if a character does not match the required dot, the matcher won’t find a dot within the previously matched alphanumeric characters. So it shouldn’t waste time trying.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^(\w+\.)*\w+$
```

You can replace `\w` with something more restrictive if you like (e.g., `[a-z]`)

Comment: I have to stare long enough to finally understand this. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
boolean ok = !str.matches(".*[^0-9a-zA-Z.].*|\\..*|.*\\.|.*\\.{2,}.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not sure if it is what you want ...):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^\\.][\\w\\.]+[^\\.]$");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern dotSeparated = Pattern.compile("^\\w+(\.\w+)*$");
```

If needed, replace `\w` by `[A-Za-z0-9]` or `\\p{Alnum}`, since `\w` allows underscores as well.

This matches one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by zero or more of [a dot, followed by one or more alphanumeric characters].